# iOS MDM payload managed app configuration, observer not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mdm

I can read from MDM payload managed app configuration below is code to read

```
func getManagedAppServerUrl() -> String? {
        if let managedConf = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") as? [String:Any] {
            if let serverURL = managedConf["server_url"] as? String{
                return serverURL
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Above code is working as expected.

I wish to get notified whenever changes are made by MDM server to **"MDM payload managed app configuration"**

i tried to add Userdefault observer on key **"com.apple.configuration.managed"** code is below to add observer

```
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "com.apple.configuration.managed", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

Callback method which will get a call once changes are made

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {//key value of mdm configraion change detection
        if let keyPathChangeDetect = keyPath {
            if keyPathChangeDetect == "com.apple.configuration.managed" {
                print("configuration change detected")
            }
        }
    }
```

But Callback method i.e *override func observeValue....* never gets a call when the server makes changes to Managed app configuration.

even if changes are made by the app using timer and changing **"com.apple.configuration.managed"** Userdefault value doesn't revoke observeValue methods.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and do not wish to set a notification on NSUserDefaults as my app is writing to that all the time, I only want to know if there is an MDM change in the managed dictionary. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Plasma I have written answer below just for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification not KVO

Comment: But, you will get other UserDefaults changes notifications also. Which will not work, if you want to get notifications only made by MDM.

Comment: I would love to hear some more details about why KVO does not work and how to prevent *any* change to UserDefaults cause the notification to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is given by @mkowal87 worked for me, here I am writing in details

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(mdmConfigChange),name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification,object: nil)
}
```

Due to the above observer method will get called multiple times, on configuration change by MDM profile, so i used some flags(user defaults saved) to check if there is actually change in configuration.

```
@objc func mdmConfigChange() -> Void {
       if let managedConf = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: com.apple.configuration.managed) as? [String:Any] {
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using Obj C but hopefully I can translate that across fairly easily! it looks like you keep a local copy of the MDM dictionary then compare with the actual MDM one when notified to see if any keys have changed correct?